# Отображение страницы после загрузки DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Интересует скрипт, который нужно прописать, чтобы страница отображалась только после ее полной загрузки. Иначе выходит некрасиво - страница отображается параллельно с загрузкой содержимого.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов решения:

```
<body style="visibility: hidden">
...
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
        }, 500);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: А таймаут-то зачем?

Comment: @Qwertiy body в момент загрузки скрыть, а после загрузки "через пол секунды" делаем видимым.

Comment: Ну так зачем полсекунды??

Comment: @Qwertiy это конечно скорее костыль, но все же практическое решение. Например в одном проекте на ангуляре пришлось сделать так. Использование ngCloak не помогло - контент прыгал.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто дал ответ , также я нашел решение по своему , выложу код сюда кому понадобится.

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js" ></script>


window.onload = function() {

var div4 = document.querySelector('.hide4');

div4 && div4.classList.remove('hide4')
         };

<style>

    .hide4 {display:none;}

</style>


<body>
<div class="hide4">

..Body Content 

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Во-первых, что за жесть, а во-вторых, а зачем тут jQuery?

Answer (score -2):

Если использовать JQ, то есть событие ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //code...
});
```